# Iterate color from colormap by integer (counter)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I try to get colors form colormaps by integer just like I would take a value from a list:

```
list[1]
```

The colormap I want to use can be found under "Qualitative ('tab20')" here:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

My code simplified:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('seaborn')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))

count=1

fig = go.Figure()

for i in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['A'], y=df[i], line_color=plt.plot_color_gradients['Qualitative']['tab20'][count]))
    count+=1

fig.show()
```

This part is pseudo-code from the example above and my core problem, I don't know how to correctly implement the colormap and how to access the colors in it by integer:

```
line_color=plt.plot_color_gradients['Qualitative']['tab20'][count]
```

I want that each trace will get a nice color from a colormap by a integer (count) and that the order the color is given is replicable. The number of traces is variable but will most likely never exceed 20.

Comment: What's the current (wrong) behavior of the code?

Comment: The pseudo-code line. I don't know how to correctly implement the colormap and how to access the colors in it by integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the colormap you want to use is tab20, which is set in matplotlib, convert it from matplotlib's colormap to hexadecimal code and store it in the list. Use that list of colors and use it in the counter of the loop process. Also, plotly has a style for seaborn, so I specified that. plotly's colormap is similar to tab20, so plotly may be all you need. See here for more [information](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as cm

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))

colors = [cm.to_hex(plt.cm.tab20(i)) for i in range(20)]

fig = go.Figure()

for i,c in enumerate(df.columns):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df.index,
        y=df[c],
        mode='lines',
        marker=dict(color=colors[i])
    ))

fig.update_layout(template='seaborn')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. very lean and sexy solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using [`fig.for_each_trace()`](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#conditionally-updating-traces) along with [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)  you can narrow this down to:

```
col_list = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet*10
counter = count(start = 0, step = 1)

fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, template = 'plotly_dark')
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line_color = col_list[next(counter)]))
```

#### Plot

[image]

One potential drawback is that you may run of out colors before you run out of traces. A hacky way to solve this would be to just make the list repeat itself a bunch of times with:

```
col_list = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet*10
```

Or you could use another approach from `itertools` with [`cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) like this:

```
col_cycle = cycle(px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet)
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, template = 'plotly_dark')
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line_color = next(col_cycle)))
```

#### Complete code for `count()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from itertools import cycle
from itertools import count

# data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,2,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum()

col_list = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet*10
counter = count(start = 0, step = 1)

# figure
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, template = 'plotly_dark')
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line_color = col_list[next(counter)]))

fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for `cycle()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from itertools import cycle
from itertools import count

# data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,2,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum()

# color cycle and figure
col_cycle = cycle(px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet)
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, template = 'plotly_dark')
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line_color = next(col_cycle)))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. The cycle tip is very usefull.

Comment: Can i ask you, is it better to use plotly.express or plotly.graph_objs?

Comment: @Veritas_in_Numeris That depends a bit on what you'd like to do. Both are extremely useful and versatile. Most of the time I build a figure structure with `px` and add elements with `fig.add_traces(go.Scatter())` for example. One thing you should know is that both approaches create the same plotly figure object.